# "PKIX path building failed" using Gradle with ZScaler

Tags: android, gradle, certificate

recently I'm facing some issues using gradle at our development department.
After our Department switched to ZScaler instead of our old VPN solution, I'm facing issues building our android app projects:

```
~ gradle clean

> Starting Daemon

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'com.example.app'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.2/gradle-7.0.2.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm using a Windows 10 x64 machine
Gradle: 5.6.4
openjdk: 11.0.2 2019-01-15
Kotlin:       1.3.41

Does someone know about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is a certificate issue. Get in touch with your it team to setup your VPN.

The issue in my case was it was not allowing to access the online gradle , google plugin repositories.

Maybe they did not whitelist them or it has not been set up in your device